# Tensorflow convolutional neural network fit error with training generator

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, image-classification

I built a simple CNN for binary image classification (cat/dog).

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')
cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=[64, 64, 3]))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
cnn.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

I got 8000 training images and made batch_size of 32. So i expect each epochs made by 250 steps. Instead when i run:

```
cnn.fit(x = training_set, validation_data = test_set, epochs = 25)
```

i get:

> Epoch 1/25
>
> X/Unknown

The X became greater than 8000! How is that possible?

I'm expeting X/250 on every epochs. Also forcing steps_epoch=250 in the fit method doesnt solve the problem. I just get X/250 but never switch to the next epoch.

What am I missig?

Comment: `history = model.fit(train_data_gen,steps_per_epoch=len(train_data_gen)//batch_size, validation_data=val_data_gen, epochs=2)`
Can you try this ?

Comment: What is the output of `len(train_datagen)`?

Comment: @Frightera i think you mean len(train_generator). It is, as expected, 250.

Comment: *I just get X/250 but never switch to the next epoch*, that's because you need to also set `validation_steps` in `fit()`. `Unknown` implies that it is an infinite dataset, I am not sure how it ends up being an infinite dataset. Are you sure you don't mix some libraries to cause this behaviour?

Comment: @Frightera tried cnn.fit(x=train_generator, validation_data=validation_generator, epochs=2, steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator), validation_steps=len(validation_generator))
Addig both steps_per_epoch and validation_steps. It seems to work. Thanks for suggesting validation_steps.

Answer (score 0):

Providing solution here from the comment section, for the benefit of the community.

> tried cnn.fit(x=train_generator, validation_data=validation_generator,
> epochs=2, steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator),
> validation_steps=len(validation_generator)) Addig both steps_per_epoch
> and validation_steps. It seems to work. Thanks for suggesting
> validation_steps.